# How to remove long horizontal scrollbar from HTML page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, browser-scrollbars

I am starting one project using twitter bootstrap, however I got one issue. There is a long empty scrollbar horizontally. I can't find the problem, does anyone knows whats the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder whn bootstrap v3 gonna get fixed with this BUG.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<style>
body {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
body > * {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Ohh it works now but why that happens? I am coding wrong html/css?

Comment: This will just hide the browser scroll bar. The .row element will still be out of bounds and you will have problems with most mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

```
media="all"
style.css:1@media (min-width: 1200px)

.container, 
.navbar-static-top .container, 
.navbar-fixed-top .container, 
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 1270px;
}
```

change to

```
.container, 
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container, 
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width:auto;
}
```

Or remove the `container` class on your map on bottom, `container` is used to wrap the content and shouldn't be wrapped into an other `container`. Also container will take full width.

> Place one anywhere within a `.container`, which sets the width of your site and content.

'*bootstrap doc*'

Check out [the templates](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps !!

1) Add the following in header to enable responsive feature

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

2) If you are using **Container fluid**

make proper use of `row-fluid` and `span` like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
        <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        <!--Body content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

there may be some tag error here ..

3) forgot to add overflow-x hidden to body.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**[LINK](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)**